# Grid Export: Item (Neo_Affiliate_Model_Affiliate) with the same id "2977" already exist

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, grid

I have custom affiliates module with grid.this affiliate module grid has list of orders placed by the affiliate customer group. in this grid i had added some columns `array('billing_name','created_at','base_grand_total','grand_total','status')` from `sales order grid` and `shipment number` from the `sales_flat_shipment` using join in magento.Following is my query.

```
$collection->join(array('og' =>'sales/order_grid'), 'main_table.order_id = og.entity_id', array('billing_name','created_at','base_grand_total','grand_total','status'));
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfs' =>'sales_flat_shipment'), 'main_table.order_id = sfs.order_id','increment_id as shipment_id');
```

I am getting this join columns added and data also populated in the affiliate grid with no issue.

The issue is when i am trying to export this grid i am getting the following issue

```
Item (Neo_Affiliate_Model_Affiliate) with the same id "2977" already exist
```

When i printed the collection object i see affiliate_id which is primary key of the affiliate module has 2977 twice.so i came to know that if primary key dupliacates then above issue comes.

in the collection i have 2977 duplicate because for order number lets assume 10000011 has 2 shipments so their collection object has 2977 twice with one record as shipment 1 and another record as shipment 2.

i had tryied this issue on google and tried many soultions like

```
1)$collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.affiliate_id');

2)$collection->getSelect()->distinct(true);

3)$collection->getSelect()->distinct('main_table.affiliate_id');
```

this issue only coming when i am trying to export.it is not coming when the grid is displaying the records.

Note:- Affiliate table contains records of orders details by affiliates

Updated:-

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
        {
            $collection = Mage::getModel('neoaffiliate/affiliate')->getCollection();
            $collection->join(array('og' =>'sales/order_grid'), 'main_table.order_id = og.entity_id', array('billing_name','created_at','base_grand_total','grand_total','status'));
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfs' =>'sales_flat_shipment'), 'main_table.order_id = sfs.order_id','increment_id as shipment_id');

            // tryed code

            //$collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.affiliate_id');
            //$collection->getSelect()->distinct(true);
            //$collection->getSelect()->distinct('main_table.affiliate_id');
            //$collection->getSelect()->distinct();

            $this->setCollection($collection);
            return parent::_prepareCollection();
        }
```

Comment: In which file did you try above changes?

Comment: in grid.php which is in the block. (Neo_Affiliate_Block_Adminhtml_Manage_Affiliate_Grid)

Comment: in _prepareCollection method

Comment: Isn't primary key supposed to be unique all the time?

Comment: primary key is unique in the affiliate table.but since because of join and my order has two shipment number for that order thats y that afiiliate order id with 2977 is repeated twice in the collection

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that for the export the collection is cloned<sup>1</sup> and any modifications that you made to the `Zend_Db_Select` instance directly get lost.

In this case I see two options:

1. override `_exportIterateCollection()` to add `$collection->getSelect()->distinct(true)` to the cloned collection, **or**
2. implement `__clone()` in the collection to always add `DISTINCT` to clones:

   ```
   public function __clone()
   {
       parent::__clone();
       $this->getSelect()->distinct(true);
   }
   ```

---

<sup>1) see: [Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_exportIterateCollection](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/cf43f51aab6125f03a0083df1c00ac0f34b86c86/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php#L948)</sup>

Comment: still not working